# Efficient way to conditionally populate elements in a pandas groupby object (possibly by applying a function)

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I'm having a problem about performance when trying to apply a function to a groupby object derived from a dataframe that has about 150,000 rows.

For simplicity, let's work on the dummy dataframe `a`

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar','bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
             ['one', 'one','two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,)), index = index)
a[1] = pd.date_range('2017-07-02', periods=10, freq='5min')


a
Out[24]: 
                     0                   1
first second                              
bar   one     0.821371 2017-07-02 00:00:00
      one     0.312364 2017-07-02 00:05:00
      two     0.104821 2017-07-02 00:10:00
baz   one     0.839370 2017-07-02 00:15:00
      two     0.307262 2017-07-02 00:20:00
foo   one     0.719300 2017-07-02 00:25:00
      two     0.371118 2017-07-02 00:30:00
      two     0.765483 2017-07-02 00:35:00
qux   one     0.794236 2017-07-02 00:40:00
      two     0.571231 2017-07-02 00:45:00
```

I want to conditionally populate the bottom element of the `0`th column in each `first`-`second` group according to the logic described in this function

```
def myfunc(g):


if( len(g) >= 2): # if each group's length is greater than or equal to 2, then:

    if ((g.loc[g.index[-1], 0] > 0.5)): # If the last element of the 0th column of the group > 0.5, then:

        time_gap = g.loc[g.index[-1], 1] - g.loc[g.index[-2], 1] # Find the time difference between the last two records in 1st column

        g.loc[g.index[-1], 0] = time_gap # and assign it to the last element in the 0th column of that group

    else: 
        g.loc[g.index[-1], 0] = 'ELSE' # Assign ELSE to the last element of the 0th column of the group    


return g
```

Applying this function yields,

```
a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second']).apply(myfunc)
Out[23]: 
  first second                0                   1
0   bar    one         0.821371 2017-07-02 00:00:00
1   bar    one             ELSE 2017-07-02 00:05:00  correct
2   bar    two         0.104821 2017-07-02 00:10:00
3   baz    one          0.83937 2017-07-02 00:15:00
4   baz    two         0.307262 2017-07-02 00:20:00
5   foo    one           0.7193 2017-07-02 00:25:00
6   foo    two         0.371118 2017-07-02 00:30:00
7   foo    two  0 days 00:05:00 2017-07-02 00:35:00  correct
8   qux    one         0.794236 2017-07-02 00:40:00
9   qux    two         0.571231 2017-07-02 00:45:00
```

The above result is exactly what I wanted. The problem is that this approach is freezing my 16GB/i5-6200U CPU @ 2.3GHz computer when applied to the dataframe where I have about 150,000 rows.

What is the most efficient way to conditionally populate such elements where (possibly) I need to write a function?

*NB: I ran this in a jupyter notebook on windows 10 - if that is important*

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues here.

1. You are editing a dataframe from within a group by apply.  This is bound for lot's of debugging.
2. When you use `apply` within a `groupby`, you create a new dataframe for every group.  We can improve performance by just manipulating the indices of the groups.
3. You don't need to reset your index in order to group by the index levels

---

To start, please make a copy of `a` just in case something gets lost in translation, I don't want you messing up `a`... just yet.

```
a_ = a.copy()
```

Ok, to make it quicker

```
g = a.groupby(level=['first', 'second'])
```

I'm going to use a lot of `get_value` and `set_value` where `takeable=True`.  The `takeable` option allows me to use the other arguments as positional references.  As, such, I'll want to make sure that I've got the correct positions.

```
j0 = a.columns.get_loc(0)
j1 = a.columns.get_loc(1)
```

Conveniently, `g` has an `indices` attribute that tells me the positions of all my rows for each named group.  I'll create a dictionary of names and indices that pass the first hurdle of being of length 2 or more using a comprehension.

```
g_ = {n: i for n, i in g.indices.items() if i.size > 1}
```

You are placing different kinds of things into column `0` and since I'm going to be using `set_value`, I'd better cast the column as `object` ahead of time.

```
a[0] = a[0].astype(object)
```

Now, I can loop over the groups that passed the length hurdle above.

```
for n, i in g_.items():
    i0, i1 = i[-2:]
    cond = a.get_value(i1, j0, takeable=True) > 0.5
    if cond:
        tgap = a.get_value(i1, j1, takeable=True) - a.get_value(i0, j1, takeable=True)
        a.set_value(i1, j0, tgap, takeable=True)
    else:
        a.set_value(i1, j0, 'ELSE', takeable=True)
```

---

**All Together**

```
g = a.groupby(level=['first', 'second'])

j0 = a.columns.get_loc(0)
j1 = a.columns.get_loc(1)
g_ = {n: i for n, i in g.indices.items() if i.size > 1}

a[0] = a[0].astype(object)

for n, i in g_.items():
    i0, i1 = i[-2:]
    cond = a.get_value(i1, j0, takeable=True) > 0.5
    if cond:
        tgap = a.get_value(i1, j1, takeable=True) - a.get_value(i0, j1, takeable=True)
        a.set_value(i1, j0, tgap, takeable=True)
    else:
        a.set_value(i1, j0, 'ELSE', takeable=True)
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second']).apply(myfunc)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.14 ms per loop

%%timeit
a = b.copy()
g = a.groupby(level=['first', 'second'])

j0 = a.columns.get_loc(0)
j1 = a.columns.get_loc(1)
g_ = {n: i for n, i in g.indices.items() if i.size > 1}

a[0] = a[0].astype(object)

for n, i in g_.items():
    i0, i1 = i[-2:]
    cond = a.get_value(i1, j0, takeable=True) > 0.5
    if cond:
        tgap = a.get_value(i1, j1, takeable=True) - a.get_value(i0, j1, takeable=True)
        a.set_value(i1, j0, tgap, takeable=True)
    else:
        a.set_value(i1, j0, 'ELSE', takeable=True)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this descriptive answer. There's so much to learn and discuss. In the meantime, can you please include the `timeit` stats(or any other performance metric that makes sense) by wrapping this inside a function for easy comparison?

Comment: @akilat90 keep in mind we can get nuttier with some complicated numpy if the improvements aren't enough

Comment: I had some catching up to do. It'd be great if you could enrich the answer a bit more, including the usage of `takeable=True` as well.

Answer (score 0):

i came up with a vectorized version to perform your transformation in several steps. If you have a rather complex transformation as you have here i would advice you to try to split it in several steps you can perfrom in pandas.

Your first step would be finding more then two entrys in a group:

```
to_check = df.groupby(['first','second']).size().apply(lambda x: True if x > 1 else False)
first  second
bar    one        True
       two       False
baz    one       False
       two       False
foo    one       False
       two        True
qux    one       False
       two       False
dtype: bool
```

Now we can merge (on the index) the results back onto the original df:

```
df = df.merge(to_check.rename('check').to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
                   one                 two  check
first second                                     
bar   one     0.821371 2017-07-02 00:00:00   True
      one     0.312364 2017-07-02 00:05:00   True
      two     0.104821 2017-07-02 00:10:00  False
baz   one     0.839370 2017-07-02 00:15:00  False
      two     0.307262 2017-07-02 00:20:00  False
foo   one     0.719300 2017-07-02 00:25:00  False
      two     0.371118 2017-07-02 00:30:00   True
      two     0.765483 2017-07-02 00:35:00   True
qux   one     0.794236 2017-07-02 00:40:00  False
      two     0.571231 2017-07-02 00:45:00  False
```

Now we can use the 'check' column to locate the groups we are interested and see if we should perform a calculation:

```
to_calc = df.loc[df['check'], 'one'].groupby(['first','second']).apply(lambda x: 1 if x[-1] > 0.5 else 'Else')
first  second
bar    one           Else
foo    two       0.394365
```

Now that we have the results we can merge them back onto the df:

```
df = df.merge(to_calc.to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
                   one                 two  check to_calc
first second                                             
bar   one     0.821371 2017-07-02 00:00:00   True    Else
      one     0.312364 2017-07-02 00:05:00   True    Else
      two     0.104821 2017-07-02 00:10:00  False     NaN
baz   one     0.839370 2017-07-02 00:15:00  False     NaN
      two     0.307262 2017-07-02 00:20:00  False     NaN
foo   one     0.719300 2017-07-02 00:25:00  False     NaN
      two     0.371118 2017-07-02 00:30:00   True       1
      two     0.765483 2017-07-02 00:35:00   True       1
qux   one     0.794236 2017-07-02 00:40:00  False     NaN
      two     0.571231 2017-07-02 00:45:00  False     NaN
```

This we can use to perform the actual calculation:

```
df_calc = df.loc[df['to_calc']==1,'two'].groupby(level=['first','second']).apply(lambda x: x[-1]-x[-2])
df = df.merge(df_calc.rename('calc').to_frame(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
                   one                 two  check to_calc     calc
first second                                                      
bar   one     0.821371 2017-07-02 00:00:00   True    Else      NaT
      one     0.312364 2017-07-02 00:05:00   True    Else      NaT
      two     0.104821 2017-07-02 00:10:00  False     NaN      NaT
baz   one     0.839370 2017-07-02 00:15:00  False     NaN      NaT
      two     0.307262 2017-07-02 00:20:00  False     NaN      NaT
foo   one     0.719300 2017-07-02 00:25:00  False     NaN      NaT
      two     0.371118 2017-07-02 00:30:00   True       1 00:05:00
      two     0.765483 2017-07-02 00:35:00   True       1 00:05:00
qux   one     0.794236 2017-07-02 00:40:00  False     NaN      NaT
      two     0.571231 2017-07-02 00:45:00  False     NaN      NaT
```

To write the result only into the last field of every group is rather tricky now, but can be achieved by combining pandas nan and duplicated test:

```
calc_select = (~pd.isnull(df['calc']))&~(
       df.duplicated(subset=['first','second'],keep='last'))
else_select = (df['to_calc']=='Else')&~(
       df.duplicated(subset=['first','second'],keep='last'))
df.loc[else_select, 'one'] =  df.loc[else_select, 'to_calc']
df.loc[calc_select, 'one'] = df.loc[calc_select, calc'].astype('O')

first second              one                 two  check to_calc     calc
0   bar    one         0.821371 2017-07-02 00:00:00   True    Else      NaT
1   bar    one             Else 2017-07-02 00:05:00   True    Else      NaT
2   bar    two         0.104821 2017-07-02 00:10:00  False     NaN      NaT
3   baz    one          0.83937 2017-07-02 00:15:00  False     NaN      NaT
4   baz    two         0.307262 2017-07-02 00:20:00  False     NaN      NaT
5   foo    one           0.7193 2017-07-02 00:25:00  False     NaN      NaT
6   foo    two         0.371118 2017-07-02 00:30:00   True       1 00:05:00
7   foo    two  0 days 00:05:00 2017-07-02 00:35:00   True       1 00:05:00
8   qux    one         0.794236 2017-07-02 00:40:00  False     NaN      NaT
9   qux    two         0.571231 2017-07-02 00:45:00  False     NaN      NaT
```

My solution actually runs slower then yours (18.4 ms compared to yours with 7.08 ms) for the test data but i would assume that the vectorized solutions runs much faster on a bigger dataset. I would really be interested if you could provide some timings with your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tillmann . As per @piRSquared 's answer, the use of `groupby` - `apply` is actually slower than just manipulating the indices. Also I'm not sure how that works under the hood despite not having to use any for loops - I wonder if we can call that as vectorization.

Comment: Hmm i'm actually surprised to hear that but then i think the performance will strongly depend on how many unique combinations of first and second you have in your df. This will determine on how many rows you are operating. Do you know how many unique combinations you have? Did you do some timings with your dataframe?

Comment: Give me some time, I'll update that tomorrow. I'm still struggling with this.

Comment: I have started a separate thread to discuss this. See if you can contribute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012503/conditionally-populating-elements-in-a-pandas-groupby-object-a-vectorized-solu?noredirect=1&lq=1)